# How to create a partially connected network using TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to create a partially connected network in TensorFlow, what is the best approach to achieve that?

This is an illustration of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Pheraps using keras functional API might work?

Comment: Yes this can be done with the functional api, there is an example in the docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional#models_with_multiple_inputs_and_outputs

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know what type of layers and how many neurons you want to use, I made them up and you will have to configure it yourself. One node in you picture depicts one layer in my example, however you can use multiple layers as well.

[image]

A demonstration with the Functional API:

```
import tensorflow as tf

node_a_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,))
node_a = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(node_a_input)
node_b = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(node_a)

node_c_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,))
node_c = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(node_c_input)
node_d = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(node_c)
node_e_merge = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([node_a, node_d]) # We have to merge the output of node_a and node_d. This can be done by concatenating, summing etc. 
node_e = tf.keras.Dense(1)(node_e_merge)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[node_a_input, node_c_input], outputs=[node_b, node_e])
```